# Flask-paginate + MongoDB full text search Error $search had wrong type when hitting page 2

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

Having an issue with flask-paginate & pyMongo/MongoDB full text search. Pagination works well for me until the user tries to search for a 'post' in the database. It will display the first 6 (as I've set it in my case) results that there are but once you want to navigate to page 2 it throws an error reading:

`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: "$search" had the wrong type. Expected string, found null, full error: {'operationTime': Timestamp(1600978481, 2), 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': '"$search" had the wrong type. Expected string, found null', 'code': 14, 'codeName': 'TypeMismatch', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1600978481, 2), 'signature': {'hash': b'\xd6b\xe7\x8eI\xa5\xea[\xb2\x0e5Y\xa2\xf3\x93R\xc6\xc1\xc4\x06', 'keyId': 6862628668309504003}}}`

The same issue arises if I try and filter the search results using `.sort("param", 1)` - I've removed this 'feature' since but this is the same error I've encountered.

Werkzeug notes that the issue arises on line 63 in my search() route ie. `pagination = Pagination(...)`.

My routes.py:

```python
@app.route('/search', methods=("GET", "POST"))
def search():
    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
    per_page = 6
    search_request = request.form.get("search")
    all_posts = mongo.db.posts.find({"$text": {"$search": search_request}}).skip((page-1) * per_page).limit(per_page)
    pagination = Pagination(
        page=page, per_page=per_page,
        total=all_posts.count(), record_name='all_posts')
    return render_template('search.html', all_posts=all_posts, pagination=pagination, search_request=search_request)
```

My search.html template:

```html
<div class="row">
        {% for post in all_posts %}
        <div class="col s12 l4">
            <div class="card card-panel hoverable">
                <div class="card-image center-align">
                    <img src="{{post.image_url}}" class="card-img">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h4 class="card-title">{{post.title}}</h4>
                    <p>{{post.description}}</p>
                    <p class="read-time">{{post.read_time}} minute(s), {{post.views}} views</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                    <a href="{{url_for('post_page', post_id=post._id)}}" class="card-link">Read</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if all_posts.count() == 0 %}
        <div class="center-align">
            <h3>No posts found</h3>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <!-- Pagination -->
    <div class="row center-align">
        {% if all_posts.count() > 1 %}
        {{ pagination.info }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ pagination.links }}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in the post, according to how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Apologies, edited now.